# Unable to connect via Mobile Broadband - But its detected - 12.10

Tags: 12.10, modem, mobile-broadband

Previously (on ubuntu 12.04), i will just connect my 3G mobile broadband modem, and will start browsing after enabling it and going through the setup process.

However, on the 12.10, I'm able to setup my connection, but it doesn't connect to the internet. All settings are okay. I've tried two different network providers in Ghana, still, i'm not able to connect.

At times, i'm notified that, its connected to the "home network" of the service provider, but disconnects in less than 10 seconds.

Is it supposed to be a bug? I've been reading about the `wvdial`, but I'm wondering something that used to be possible by "default" in Ubuntu should now be "configured" via a software.

Help!

Comment: What are you using? A USB stick, a portable hotspot or an internal modem?

Comment: Let me guess, you are using a Huawei data card? Just install 'BAM Huawei mobile partner' on Linux. Just Google it. (Should be a zip file around 15mb) it will install the proper modem driver

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I'm on it. Will feedback on the outcome. Yes! I'm using a Huawei K3770 (vodafone brand)

Comment: Okay guys. Got it working via the bam huawei software. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happened  due to bugs(or bug) in the ModemManager 0.6.0.0 which shipped with Ubuntu 12.10. You can remove this modem manager version and downgrade in to 0.5.2.

To check modem manager version : `dpkg -s modemmanager`

download 0.5.2 version : [link 64](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/98148167/modemmanager_0.5.2.0-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb) --- [i386](http://mirror.pnl.gov/ubuntu//pool/main/m/modemmanager/modemmanager_0.5.2.0-0ubuntu2_i386.deb)

Comment: thanks Chandana. This has been the answer i've been waiting for. I knew it works by default.But the 12.10 couldn't work. well, thanks. However, the i386 link reaches dead-end. Please, fix that for me. or get an alternative for me. :)

Comment: @Chandana: Excellent. I've had been looking for your answer since May-14.