# Mobile Broadband Modem will not connect with Kernel 3.11 Ubuntu 12.04.4

Tags: 12.04, mobile-broadband, modem-manager

My Mobile Broadband modem works with Kernel 3.2.0-58-generic #88-Ubuntu SMP, however it fails to complete a connection with the new 3.11 Kernel. Does anyone have a solution to enable the modem with the 3.11 Kernel

Ubuntu Version is 12.04.4

Modem is a Serria Wireless

Here is some log data

The first section is OK - connected

```
modem-manager[1194]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager/Modems/0: state changed (connecting -> connected)
NetworkManager[1222]: <info> Activation (wwan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
NetworkManager[1222]: <info> Activation (wwan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
NetworkManager[1222]: <info> (wwan0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
NetworkManager[1222]: <info> (wwan0): bringing up device.
NetworkManager[1222]: <info> Activation (wwan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.
NetworkManager[1222]: <info> Activation (wwan0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) scheduled.
NetworkManager[1222]: <info> Activation (wwan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
NetworkManager[1222]: <info> Activation (wwan0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) started...
NetworkManager[1222]: <info> (wwan0): device state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
NetworkManager[1222]: <info> Activation (wwan0) Beginning DHCPv4 transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
NetworkManager[1222]: <info> dhclient started with pid 5191
NetworkManager[1222]: <info> Activation (wwan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
NetworkManager[1222]: <info> Activation (wwan0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) complete.
NetworkManager[1222]: <info> Activation (wwan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) started...
NetworkManager[1222]: <info> Activation (wwan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) complete.
```

This section failed to connect

```
NetworkManager[1288]: <info> Auto-activating connection 'Telstra  (Next G) '.
NetworkManager[1288]: <info> Activation (wwan0) starting connection 'Telstra  (Next G) '
NetworkManager[1288]: <info> (wwan0): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
NetworkManager[1288]: <info> Activation (wwan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
NetworkManager[1288]: <info> Activation (wwan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
NetworkManager[1288]: <info> Activation (wwan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
modem-manager[1214]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager/Modems/0: state changed (registered -> connecting)
modem-manager[1214]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager/Modems/0: state changed (connecting -> connected)
NetworkManager[1288]: <info> Activation (wwan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
NetworkManager[1288]: <info> Activation (wwan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
NetworkManager[1288]: <info> (wwan0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
NetworkManager[1288]: <info> (wwan0): bringing up device.
NetworkManager[1288]: <info> Activation (wwan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.
NetworkManager[1288]: <info> Activation (wwan0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) scheduled.
NetworkManager[1288]: <info> Activation (wwan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
NetworkManager[1288]: <info> Activation (wwan0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) started...
NetworkManager[1288]: <info> (wwan0): device state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
NetworkManager[1288]: <info> Activation (wwan0) Beginning DHCPv4 transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
NetworkManager[1288]: <info> dhclient started with pid 23608
NetworkManager[1288]: <info> Activation (wwan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
NetworkManager[1288]: <info> Activation (wwan0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) complete.
NetworkManager[1288]: <info> Activation (wwan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) started...
NetworkManager[1288]: <info> Activation (wwan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) complete.
kernel: [ 1116.168922] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wwan0: link is not ready
NetworkManager[1288]: <warn> (wwan0): DHCPv4 request timed out.
NetworkManager[1288]: <info> (wwan0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 23608
NetworkManager[1288]: <info> Activation (wwan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
NetworkManager[1288]: <info> Activation (wwan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) started...
NetworkManager[1288]: <info> (wwan0): device state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable') [70 120 5]
NetworkManager[1288]: <warn> Activation (wwan0) failed.
NetworkManager[1288]: <info> Activation (wwan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) complete.
NetworkManager[1288]: <info> (wwan0): device state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
NetworkManager[1288]: <info> (wwan0): deactivating device (reason 'none') [0]
modem-manager[1214]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager/Modems/0: state changed (connected -> disconnecting)
NetworkManager[1288]: <info> Policy set 'Wired - Home Network' (eth0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
NetworkManager[1288]: <info> Policy set 'Wired - Home Network' (eth0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
 modem-manager[1214]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager/Modems/0: state changed (disconnecting -> registered)
 NetworkManager[1288]: <info> Auto-activating connection 'Telstra  (Next G) '.
 NetworkManager[1288]: <info> Activation (wwan0) starting connection 'Telstra  (Next G) '
 NetworkManager[1288]: <info> (wwan0): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
 NetworkManager[1288]: <info> Activation (wwan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
 NetworkManager[1288]: <info> Activation (wwan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
 NetworkManager[1288]: <info> Activation (wwan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
 modem-manager[1214]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager/Modems/0: state changed (registered -> connecting)
 modem-manager[1214]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager/Modems/0: state changed (connecting -> connected)
 NetworkManager[1288]: <info> Activation (wwan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
 NetworkManager[1288]: <info> Activation (wwan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
 NetworkManager[1288]: <info> (wwan0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
 NetworkManager[1288]: <info> (wwan0): bringing up device.
 NetworkManager[1288]: <info> Activation (wwan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.
 NetworkManager[1288]: <info> Activation (wwan0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) scheduled.
 NetworkManager[1288]: <info> Activation (wwan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
 NetworkManager[1288]: <info> Activation (wwan0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) started...
 NetworkManager[1288]: <info> (wwan0): device state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
 NetworkManager[1288]: <info> Activation (wwan0) Beginning DHCPv4 transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
 kernel: [ 1166.280233] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wwan0: link is not ready
 NetworkManager[1288]: <info> dhclient started with pid 25900
 NetworkManager[1288]: <info> Activation (wwan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
 NetworkManager[1288]: <info> Activation (wwan0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) complete.
 NetworkManager[1288]: <info> Activation (wwan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) started...
 NetworkManager[1288]: <info> Activation (wwan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) complete.
 NetworkManager[1288]: <info> (wwan0): DHCPv4 state changed nbi -> preinit
 NetworkManager[1288]: <warn> (wwan0): DHCPv4 request timed out.
 NetworkManager[1288]: <info> (wwan0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 25900
 NetworkManager[1288]: <info> Activation (wwan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
 NetworkManager[1288]: <info> Activation (wwan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) started...
 NetworkManager[1288]: <info> (wwan0): device state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable') [70 120 5]
 NetworkManager[1288]: <info> Marking connection 'Telstra  (Next G) ' invalid.
 NetworkManager[1288]: <warn> Activation (wwan0) failed.
 NetworkManager[1288]: <info> Activation (wwan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) complete.
 modem-manager[1214]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager/Modems/0: state changed (connected -> disconnecting)
 NetworkManager[1288]: <info> (wwan0): device state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
 NetworkManager[1288]: <info> (wwan0): deactivating device (reason 'none') [0]
```

Answer (score 0):

An excellent solution from Chandana. Be quoted:

This happened due to bugs(or bug) in the ModemManager 0.6.0.0 which shipped with Ubuntu 12.10. You can remove this modem manager version and downgrade in to 0.5.2.

To check modem manager version :

> dpkg -s modemmanager

download 0.5.2 version : [link 64](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/98148167/modemmanager_0.5.2.0-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb) --- [i386](http://mirror.pnl.gov/ubuntu//pool/main/m/modemmanager/modemmanager_0.5.2.0-0ubuntu2_i386.deb)

Source: [Unable to connect via Mobile Broadband - But its detected - 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207652/unable-to-connect-via-mobile-broadband-but-its-detected-12-10?rq=1) section: Chandana's answer.