# The mobile broadband (express card Sierra wireless aircard 890) is no longer able to connect 3G network, after installing new U 14.04 LTS,

Tags: 14.04, mobile-broadband, expresscard

When I ran Ubuntu 13.10 and previous version, I can use Mobile broadband/ express card (the Sierra wireless aircard 890) to access internet via 3G.
After installing new 14.04 LTS, the thing has gone. I can no longer use the express card. When I chose to connect 3G via the "Mobile broadband", it does automatically dropout  the netwotk, just immediately. The card's hotter than when running in previous version of Ubuntu.
How to check which part causing the trouble, then fix it, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer, thank to Chandana.
Be quoted:

This happened due to bugs(or bug) in the ModemManager 0.6.0.0 which shipped with Ubuntu 12.10. You can remove this modem manager version and downgrade in to 0.5.2.

To check modem manager version :

> dpkg -s modemmanager

download 0.5.2 version : [link 64](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/98148167/modemmanager_0.5.2.0-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb) --- [i386](http://mirror.pnl.gov/ubuntu//pool/main/m/modemmanager/modemmanager_0.5.2.0-0ubuntu2_i386.deb)

Source: [Unable to connect via Mobile Broadband - But its detected - 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207652/unable-to-connect-via-mobile-broadband-but-its-detected-12-10?rq=1)
section: Chandana's answer.